# How to get rid of NA tick mark in ggplot and make it stop drawing error bar for month that the value is 0?

Tags: r, ggplot2, na, errorbar

I have a 13 month time series from September-September (month of March is no data but included because of the time series aspect)that I am trying to make a bar plot of. I need error bars, and am using geom_errorbar, but I do not want it to draw a line for March. I also am having trouble with the axis ticks. The second September value is always labelled as NA. This is the code that I have.

[image: This is the plot it makes.]

```
bay <- ggplot(stn1, aes(x = factor(Month, level = c("SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC", "JAN", "FEB",
"MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEPTEMBER")), y = Temperature))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())+
  theme_classic()+
  xlab("Month")+
  ylab("Temperature°C")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Temperature-Temperature_sd, ymax=Temperature+Temperature_sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) 
print(bay)
```

I tried using scale_x_discrete() to manually change the NA, but it did not work.

Comment: That error suggests you have more than `c("SEP", ..., "SEPTEMBER")` values within your `Month`. I suggest you look at `unique(stn1$Month)` and see what is different, including spelling, case, etc. (BTW, it's `levels=`, not `level=`, R is doing a partial-match for you but that's not a good habit.)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Bailey Lin! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a good start here!) and sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.